# Prove that $\frac{mn}{1+m+n}\ge\frac{1}{3}$ for $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis

How do I prove that $\min A = \frac{1}{3}$ for: $$\left\{m,n\in\mathbb{N}:\frac{mn}{1+m+n}\right\}$$

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is same as proving $1+m+n \leq 3mn$

Same as proving $\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{mn} \leq 3$

Since $m,n \geq 1$,

$\Rightarrow \frac{1}{m} \leq 1, \frac{1}{n} \leq 1, \frac{1}{mn} \leq 1$

Thus the result follows. Equality holds when $m=n=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is the following:

$\frac{mn}{1+m+n}=\frac{2+mn}{1+m+n}-\frac{2}{1+m+n}\geq1-\frac{2}{1+m+n}\geq 1-\frac{2}{3}=\frac{1}{3} $

Note that the first inequality follows since $(1-m)(1-n)\geq 0$ for $n$ and $m$  greater (or equal) than $1$.

Equality is obtained when $m=n=1$, thus the minimum is $1/3$.